# Dropping system.profile collection from mongodb slave

Tags: mongodb

According to this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling, each replica set has a different system.profile collection. I'm trying to drop `system.profile` collection from one of the replica using:

```
> rs.slaveOk()
> db.setProfilingLevel(0)
> db.system.profile.drop()
2016-10-12T06:42:29.187+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: drop failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master", "code" : 10107 } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.drop@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:739:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I am not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: What if you type `db.getProfilingStatus()`?

Comment: I'm able to change the profiling status easily. `db.setProfilingLevel(0)` sets the profiling level to 0.

Answer (score 2):

The drop command is failing because the node is not in the "Primary" state. A drop collection command is a write operation; write operations are only permitted on the Primary.

The easiest way to remove the "system.profile" collection would be to drop the collection on the Primary node. The drop command will be replicated to other nodes; entries for the drop command can be seen in the oplog:

```
$ db.oplog.rs.find()
....
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1477445036, 1), "h" : NumberLong("1583532073473005081"), "v" : 2, "op" : "c", "ns" : "stack.$cmd", "o" : { "drop" : "system.profile" } }
```

The problem you may be encountering could be a result of profiling being enabled on the Secondary node when the drop command was executed.

If you attempt to drop the "system.profile" command with profiling enabled, the drop command will fail and display an error:

```
$ db.system.profile.drop()
2016-10-25T18:28:43.030-0700 E QUERY    Error: drop failed: {
    "ns" : "stack.system.profile",
    "nIndexesWas" : 0,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "turn off profiling before dropping system.profile collection",
    "code" : 20
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBCollection.drop (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:620:15)
    at (shell):1:19 at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:620
```

Profiling can be disabled on the Primary allowing the drop command to be executed. However, if profiling is still enabled on the Secondary, the replication of the drop command would fail and the collection would still exist. From the mongodb.log file:

```
2016-10-25T17:46:02.123-0700 W REPL     [repl writer worker 15] repl Failed command { drop: "system.profile" } on stack with status IllegalOperation turn off profiling before dropping system.profile collection during oplog application
```

This would result in a weird state, as the collection would not exist on the Primary but would exist on the Secondary. Disabling profiling on the Secondary node and attempting to drop the command again would not remove the collection; the drop command on a non-existent collection would essentially be a no-op, which would not create an oplog entry and not be replicated.

A new "system.profile" collection would need to be created on the Primary, which could then be dropped, allowing the command to be replicated and dropped on the other node(s):

```
2016-10-25T18:18:18.093-0700 I COMMAND  [repl writer worker 15] CMD: drop stack.system.profile
```

---

Is the node in question Primary eligible? You may want to consider initiating a failover and promoting the node to the Primary state. This would simplify the process of removing this collection.

---

Marco is also correct: restarting the node in question in a stand-alone state would also allow for removing the collection. The node could then be re-inserted back into the replica set.

Comment: I verified that db.getProfilingLevel() returns 0 on all nodes. And then created a new system.profile collection on primary. After that I dropped system.profile node from primary, but that change didn't propagate to secondary nodes. Anyways, I solved this by forcing each node to become primary one by one and then dropping the system.profile collection individually.

Comment: Did you check the logs of the node where the drop failed to replicate? It may offer some info on why the collection wasn't dropped. Is it possible that profiling was disabled in the database you checked but still enabled on the database where the system.profile collection existed?

Comment: Yes, there was nothing in the log. Also I don't think profiling was enabled on other databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but having a look at the documentation, if you need to do some generic maintenance operations on a secondary node in a replica set:

1. You need to stop the secondary
2. Restart the secondary as a standalone on a different port
3. Perform the operations you need
4. Restart mongodb as a member of the replica set

These are the needed steps to change the size of the `system.profile` collection on a secondary ([link to documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/)), so I assume dropping the same collection should follow the same instructions.

Comment: Any reason why I need to stop the secondary? I can easily drop the system.profile on a primary node. Also system.profile is a capped collection so I can't even drop documents from it.

Comment: That's what I found on the documentation to perform some general maintenance on a secondary node of a replica set, so I assume dropping and recreating the `system.profile` collection should follow the same procedure. I didn't develop MongoDB so my answer is based on what I saw from the documentation. Maybe, since the system collections on a secondary are somehow related to the main node, there should be some kind of "protection" that prevents _backyard changes_.